# Why does this AWS instance provisioned by Vagrant terminate as soon as it comes up?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, vagrant

My Vagrant provisioned AWS instance will terminate as soon as it comes up.

Here's my config file:

```
  config.vm.box = "aws-dummy"
  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"

  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/vagrant", type: "rsync"


  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = "MY ID"
    aws.secret_access_key = "MY SECRET KEY GOES HERE"
    aws.keypair_name = "cb"
    aws.ami = "ami-f77fbeb3"
    aws.instance_ready_timeout = 300
    aws.instance_type = "t2.small"
    aws.tags = {
        "Name" => "VagrantUniversal",
    }

    aws.associate_public_ip = true
    aws.availability_zone = "us-west-1a"
    aws.subnet_id = "subnet-f2245XXX"

    aws.private_ip_address = "10.1.10.10"
    aws.security_groups = [ 'sg-4084dXXX' ] # 
    aws.region = "us-west-1"
    # aws.block_device_mapping = [{ 'DeviceName' => '/dev/sda1', 'Ebs.VolumeSize' => 50 }]

    override.ssh.username = "centos"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "../keys/cb.pem"
  end
```

I took out the provisioning part to eliminate that possibility. I also tried commenting out the synced_folder

From the log:

```
 INFO interface: info: Machine is booted and ready for use!
 INFO interface: info: ==> default: Machine is booted and ready for use!
==> default: Machine is booted and ready for use!
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x00000100a3d5f8@/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001028a1058>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100a4e290>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Extras::Action::DNS::ProviderIsAWS:0x00000100a57368>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Extras::Action::DNS::ProviderIsAWS:0x00000100a57368>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x00000100a859e8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x000001023ca7f0@/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x00000100a85970>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadSSHInfo:0x00000102968220>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Extras::Action::DNS::ConnectAWS:0x000001029a1160>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Extras::Action::DNS::Set:0x000001029da5f0>
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `records' for nil:NilClass
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `records' for nil:NilClass
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
ERROR warden: Error occurred: undefined method `records' for nil:NilClass
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Calling recover: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001028a1058>
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Recovery complete.
 INFO warden: Calling recover: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001028a10a8>
 INFO warden: Beginning recovery process...
 INFO warden: Calling recover: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::RunInstance:0x00000100a17650>
 INFO machine: Calling action: read_state on provider AWS (i-41bcaa81)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_read_state #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000104342c90>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x000001043480a0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x00000104348028>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x000001043a9f30>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x000001043a9f30>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x00000104348028>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x000001043480a0>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001009a6068>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x000001009b4e60>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000100a1f0a8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::DestroyConfirm:0x00000100a1c290>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::DestroyConfirm:0x00000100a1c290>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x00000100a54dc0>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x00000100a96d88@/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x00000100a54d48>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::Call:0x00000100a54d20>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x000001029bb920>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x000001029b8180>
 INFO machine: Calling action: read_state on provider AWS (i-41bcaa81)
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 2 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_read_state #<Vagrant::Action::Builder:0x00000101036a40>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x0000010283bd20>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x0000010283baf0>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x000001022c69f8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ReadState:0x000001022c69f8>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x0000010283baf0>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ConfigValidate:0x0000010283bd20>
 INFO warden: Calling OUT action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::IsCreated:0x000001029b8180>
 INFO runner: Preparing hooks for middleware sequence...
 INFO runner: 3 hooks defined.
 INFO runner: Running action: machine_action_up #<Vagrant::Action::Warden:0x000001040a93a8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x0000010432b7c0@/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ConnectAWS:0x000001040a9218>
 INFO connect_aws: Connecting to AWS...
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::ElbDeregisterInstance:0x00000104179990>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<VagrantPlugins::AWS::Action::TerminateInstance:0x000001028962e8>
 INFO interface: info: Terminating the instance...
 INFO interface: info: ==> default: Terminating the instance...
==> default: Terminating the instance...
 INFO machine: New machine ID: nil
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Vagrant::Action::Builtin::ProvisionerCleanup:0x000001042392b8>
 INFO warden: Calling IN action: #<Proc:0x000001042c1258@/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.4/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:94 (lambda)>
```

...and here's the gist of the log w/o the debug info:

```
==> default: Launching an instance with the following settings...
==> default:  -- Type: t2.small
==> default:  -- AMI: ami-f77fbeb3
==> default:  -- Region: us-west-1
==> default:  -- Availability Zone: us-west-1a
==> default:  -- Keypair: cb
==> default:  -- Subnet ID: subnet-f2245XXX
==> default:  -- Private IP: 10.1.10.10
==> default:  -- Security Groups: ["sg-4084dXXX"]
==> default:  -- Block Device Mapping: []
==> default:  -- Terminate On Shutdown: false
==> default:  -- Monitoring: false
==> default:  -- EBS optimized: false
==> default:  -- Assigning a public IP address in a VPC: true
==> default: Waiting for instance to become "ready"...
==> default: Waiting for SSH to become available...
==> default: Machine is booted and ready for use!
==> default: Terminating the instance...
/Users/swirsky/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-aws-extras-0.1.0/lib/vagrant-aws-extras/action/dns.rb:61:in `call': undefined method `records' 
for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I'm running Vagrant v1.7.4, vagrant-aws (0.6.0), vagrant-aws-extras (0.1.0), ruby 2.0.0p481

If I remove the `vagrant-aws-extras` plugin, I get this curious message:

> mkdir -p '/vagrant'
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
>
> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed! mkdir -p '/vagrant'
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

Comment: If I remove the vagrant-aws-extras plugin, I get this curious message:

`mkdir -p '/vagrant'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p '/vagrant'

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`

Comment: To attract an answer, try rephrasing your question so it's about a specific Vagrant configuration-- try different configuration combinations to figure out what trigger the issue. Or re-work the question to ask what might cause the error message you pasted into your comment.

Comment: It's not clear what command is run here, `vagrant up`, `vagrant provision`, `vagrant reload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This potentially could be a bug of `vagrant-aws-extras` plugin, since other people reported this issue as well, see: [GH vagrant-aws #442](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/issues/442). Or potentially it's misconfiguration of your image box.

Since it's not clear which command are you invoking, but if you're invoking [`vagrant reload`](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/reload.html), it's terminating your instance by design, since it's just running a `halt` followed by an `up`, so it's normal. However the problem is that it's not up'ing up properly, because of the following error:

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

I had similar problem with `reload` which has been reported at [GH vagrant #7244](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7244).

So for workaround is to destroy the machine and provision it again. Or if you'd like to run provisioning again on the running instance, just run `vagrant provision` to avoid invoking shutdown command.

It also possible the problem is not caused by the shutdown command it-self, but the above error coming as result of running `mkdir -p '/vagrant'`.

The best is to use the image that doesn't require tty with sudo. Otherwise configure your image to not require password, since Vagrant by default assumes that the `sudo` command doesn't require typing the password.

Also commenting out `Defaults requiretty` from `/etc/sudoers` could help. Or use `config.ssh.pty = true` option to get a tty.

See: [GH #1482 for vagrant - Can't execute sudo commands on machine that requires tty to run sudo](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1482)